# Powershell - Add Row Count To Existing Script

Tags: powershell

I'm putting together a Powershell script which will return information on all files in a given directory:

```
Folder Name
File Name
Last Write Time
File Size (MB)
```

I'm just missing one final piece of information and I've spent the last 5 hours trying to include the number of rows contained within each file without any success whatsoever.  I would be extremely grateful if I could get some help on this, thanks.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
Clear-Host

$UpstreamFile = 'C:\MyFolder'
$OutputFile   = 'C:\FileInformation.csv'

Get-Childitem $UpstreamFile -rec | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
Select-Object @{Name="FolderLocation"; Expression={$UpstreamFile}}, @{Name="FileName"; Expression={$_.Name.ToUpper()}}, 
@{Name="LastWriteTime"; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")}}, @{Name="FileSizeMB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Mb}} | Export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path $OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text based files you can pipe the results of Get-Content to Measure-Object then Select-Object. I'm not entirely sure what the outcome will be for binary files.

```
Get-Content <filename> | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

This could be included in your existing script by adding another entry before the pipe to Export-CSV.

```
Select-Object @{Name="FolderLocation"; Expression={$UpstreamFile}}, 
@{Name="FileName"; Expression={$_.Name.ToUpper()}}, 
@{Name="LastWriteTime"; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")}}, 
@{Name="FileSizeMB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Mb}}, 
@{Name="Rows"; Expression={ (Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object | Select Count) }} | Export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path $OutputFile
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however I'm a little confused as to how to integrate your suggestion into the syntax I'm using.  I've played around with your example and spent hours on Google without any luck.  Could you please advise as to how the two pieces of code can be integrated?

Comment: Answer has been editted. Hope this helps explain it a bit better.